# Android read with O_DIRECT from native code

Tags: android, io, java-native-interface, storage, native

I am trying to read a file with `O_DIRECT` flag, from native code. I use the `_SC_PAGESIZE` to align the buffer and I read in chunks of 4KB. When I read the file from internal storage, it works fine. However, when I read from external, emulated storage (on my Sone Xperia M), read returns `EINVAL`. What could be the problem? Does alignment change by file system? Should I do a different alignment for the second partition?

Comment: For what purpose are you using the `O_DIRECT` flag ? (I mean, what is the use-case requiring such a solution). Also, what version of Android are you running ? (It seems that this flag has been disabled in Kitkat https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67406).

Comment: I want to bypass the caching. Also, I am running on 4.3. It makes it more strange when the code works for one partition but not the other.

Comment: Bypassing the cache is the solution, not the use-case. What is the *end* use-cache of bypassing the cache ?